# Converting Russian letters for rtf template file

Tags: php

To fill my rtf template, I need to convert a string with Russian and Polish letters to format based on Decimal NCR - it is for example `ж -> '\u1078?'`

Function `'is_special(char)'` define is letter from Russian alphabet.

Function `'convert_spec_char(char)'` return new value of letter`(eg. '\u1078?')`

And when I'm calling the function it only convert first letter third letter, and so on.. and I don't understand why it doesn't work. Any ideas about what is wrong in the code?

```
convert_string("лошадь-koń") \\ result '\u1083?о\u1096?а\u1076?ь-ko\u324?'
convert_string("польша"); \\ result '\u1087?о\u1083?ь\u1096?а'

$arr_to_change = array("а" => "\u1072?","б" => "\u1073?","в" => "\u1074?","г" => "\u1075?","д" => "\u1076?","е" => "\u1077?","ё" => "\u1105?","ж" => "\u1078?","з" => "\u1079?","и" => "\u1080?","й" => "\u1081?","к" => "\u1082?","л" => "\u1083?","м" => "\u1084?", "н" => "\u1085?","о" => "\u1086?","п" => "\u1087?","р" => "\u1088?","с" => "\u1089?","т" => "\u1090?","у" => "\u1091?","ф" => "\u1092?","х" => "\u1093?","ц" => "\u1094?","ч" => "\u1095?","ш" => "\u1096?","щ" => "\u1097?","ъ" => "\u1098?","ы" => "\u1099?","ь" => "\u1100?","э" => "\u1101?","ю" => "\u1102?","я" => "\u1103?","А" => "\u1040?","Б" => "\u1041?","В" => "\u1042?","Г" => "\u1043?","Д" => "\u1044?","Е" => "\u1045?","Ё" => "\u1025?","Ж" => "\u1046?","З" => "\u1047?","И" => "\u1048?","Й" => "\u1049?","К" => "\u1050?","Л" => "\u1051?","М" => "\u1052?","Н" => "\u1053?","О" => "\u1054?", "П" => "\u1055?","Р" => "\u1056?","С" => "\u1057?","Т" => "\u1058?","У" => "\u1059?","Ф" => "\u1060?", "Х" => "\u1061?","Ц" => "\u1062?","Ч" => "\u1063?","Ш" => "\u1064?","Щ" => "\u1065?","Ъ" => "\u1066?","Ы" => "\u1067?","Ь" => "\u1068?","Э" => "\u1069?","Ю" => "\u1070?","Я" => "\u1071?","ą" => "\u261?","ć" => "\u263?", "ę" => "\u281?","ł" => "\u322?","ń" => "\u324?", "ó" => "\u243?","ś" => "\u347?", "ź" => "\u378?","ż" => "\u380?","Ą" => "\u260?","Ć" => "\u262?","Ę" => "\u280?","Ł" => "\u321?","Ń" => "\u323?","Ó" => "\u211?","Ś" =>"\u346?","Ź" => "\u377?","Ż" => "\u379?");

function convert_string($string)
{

    for($i = 0; $i < count($string); )
    {
    $string = str_split($string);
        if(isset($string[$i+1]) && is_special($string[$i].$string[$i+1]))
        {
            $string[$i] = convert_spec_char($string[$i].$string[$i+1]);
            array_splice($string, $i+1, 1);
            $i += 2;
        }
        else
            $i++;
    }
return implode("",$string);
}
function is_special($letter)
{
    global $arr_to_change;
    foreach($arr_to_change as $key => $value)
    {
        if($letter == $key)
                return true;
    }
    return false;


}

function convert_spec_char($letter)
{

    global $arr_to_change;
    foreach($arr_to_change as $key => $value)
    {
        if($letter == $key)
                return $value;
    }
    return $letter;


}
```

Comment: can you work with this ? http://ideone.com/GPRoER

Comment: Thanks, that's good solution I'll use it but anyway I would like to find out why my code doesn't work...